# Using the Requests library for certificate authentication, how to read the certificate as byte/stream and then afferent it into the "send" function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, python-requests

Python uses the requests library for certificate authentication, but in sessions, certificates can only be passed in by path. Is there any way to pass certificates in the form of byte/stream into the parameters of send, or is there any other library supporting this way?

I have read the Source code of the requests library and try to find the other way to solve my problem, but i failed.Of course, I haved tried to find other libraries to send certificates as byte/stream, but not.

```py
verify='path/to/verify'
certt='path/to/ceert'
r=requests.Session.send(prepared(),cert=cert,verify=verify)
```

Can "cert" or "vertify" be byte/stream , not only path?